# Remove all numbers and "{" from a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, replaceall

I am trying to remove all non numeric characters from the String Array as require to compare it with the list of numbers. The split works but I am not able to compare the two Sets

```
for(String w:a1)
    {
        w=w.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

        if(dContacts.getNumber().equals(w))
        {
            System.out.println("Compared1234567");
        }

        System.out.println("---6545678909876789876hijkhijkhijkjh"+dContacts.getNumber());
        System.out.println("Arraylistextract"+w);
    }
```

Comment: Why does `String a = "hello"; a.concat(" world!"); System.out.println(a);` not print "hello world!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, **Strings are immutable**. This means that `w.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");` will create a *different* String, and `w` will remain the same. Assign that expression to `w` to store it:

```
w = w.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a string without reassigning it to either the same variable or a new one.

Answer (score 0):

String is Immutable so if you are calling some function then it will not change in same object.

you have to change this line to

```
w= w.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```